# Solve Nonlinear Differential Equation $v^2_y = -\frac{1}{3}v^3 + cv^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to know how to solve the above equation.
The equation comes about when reducing a PDE by finding the symmetries of the PDE and then applying one of them.
I want to understand how the solution is found.
The answer given is
$$
v = 3c \frac{1}{\cosh ^2 \left[\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{cy} + \delta \right]}
$$

(I had to use the $\frac{1}{\cosh}$ as \sech is not recognised.)

Comment: Let's look at a simpler example. Consider the differential equation $v_y=v$. This has general solution $v=C(x)e^y$ where $C$ is an arbitrary function of one real variable. That being said, I believe you can solve your differential equation by considering an analogous ODE $(y')^2=-\frac{1}{3}y^3+y^2$

Comment: To generate $\operatorname{sech}$ you can use `\operatorname{}`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Matthew Pilling commented, considering the differential equation
$$(v')^2=-\frac 13 v^3+v^2$$ it could be an idea to swith variables first to have
$$(y')^2=\frac{3}{(3-v) v^2}\implies y'=\pm \frac{\sqrt 3 } {v\sqrt{3-v} }$$ Integrating
$$y+C=\pm\int \frac{\sqrt 3 } {v\sqrt{3-v} } dv$$
$$I=\int \frac{\sqrt 3 } {v\sqrt{3-v} } dv=\log \left(1-\sqrt{1-\frac{v}{3}}\right)-\log \left(1+\sqrt{1-\frac{v}{3}}\right)$$
$$I=-2 \tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{v}{3}}\right)$$ Then $v$ and use the hyperbolic half-angle substitution.

Comment: There a typo in the first Eqn.it should be $-v^3/3$.

Answer (score 0):

$$v'^2=-\frac{1}{3}v^3+v^2 \implies v'=\pm(v^2-v^3/3)$$
$$\implies \int\frac{dv}{\sqrt{v^2-v^3/3}}=\pm \int dx \implies \int \frac{dv}{v\sqrt{1-v/3}}=\pm x+C.$$
Let $1-v/3=u^2$, then
$$\int \frac{-2du}{1-u^2}=C \pm x \implies \ln \frac{u-1}{u+1}=C\pm x$$
$$\implies u=\frac{1+e^{C\pm x}}{1-e^{c\pm x}}\implies u=-\coth [(C\pm x)/2].$$
$$\implies v(x)=-3 \text{csch}^2(C\pm x)/2]$$
Since $C$ is arbitrary: $$v(x)=-3\text{sech}^2(C\pm x)/2].$$ can also be a solution.

Comment: v is a function of y, so I would have y in place of x, I realised that I left out the $c$ coeffiecient of the $v^2$ term. However, I don't think that will affect the method you have shown. I am comparing what I have done with your post to step through it.